# React: If children is a part of props, then why doesn't it re-render the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A React component re-renders when its props change. Ok.
But its children are passed through props: the children prop, most of the time.

So: when a child is re-rendered, because its state changed for example (it could be triggered by a change event), the children changes, doesn't it? If it changes, the prop.children changes too. If prop.children changes, the component should re-render. And the same for its parent and all its ancestors!

So the tiniest "leaf" component change should trigger all the component tree to re-render! But it does not, and I don't get why...

Could anyone bring some light?

Comment: When you pass children to a component you are passing *component descriptors*, not component instances. React uses those descriptors to render/instantiate the component. A state change inside a component doesn't change its descriptor.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.